# Pairing in Core Bluetooth Peripheral application iOS

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

I have created an application in IPhone that can act as a BLE Peripheral.I want to initiate a pairing mechanism when a central send a request to connect. I have searched on net and came to know that individual characteristic can be encrypted and initiate pairing when read by central. I have read the 
 [Bluetooth 4.0 and 4.1 security document](https://developer.bluetooth.org/TechnologyOverview/Pages/LE-Security.aspx)  which is saying there are various pairing mechanism are available.But i don't know how to use it in my application. Can anyone help?

Code i am using for creating the characteristic

```
var characteristic = CBMutableCharacteristic(type: charId, properties: charProperties, value: nil, permissions:CBAttributePermissions.ReadEncryptionRequired|CBAttributePermissions.WriteEncryptionRequired)
```

Comment: Can you show the code you are using?  Simply set the read encryption required or write encryption required on one of your characteristics. iOS will do the rest

Comment: I have updated the code i am using for creating the characteristic. As it is pairing when central request to read or write a characteristic. I want that the peripheral should pair when a central send a  connection request to the peripheral.

Comment: You can't do that in iOS. A connection can be initiated without pairing (actually bonding in this case) - pairing/bonding is only initiated when the encrypted characteristic is read.

Comment: I have use light blue with my app, even i didn't give any encryption at that time. When I am tapping  my peripheral  to connect in Light Blue app it is asking for pairing somehow. Do u have any idea how this can happen ?

Comment: Because LightBlue will read all characteristics as soon as it connects

Comment: But i didnt give any characteristic with encrypted permission or property at that time. I didn't use encryption word at all.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77282/discussion-between-paulw11-and-sunil-kumar).

Comment: I have remove encryption and also check in Xcode that their should not be any encryption word in my project. I connect it with light blue and it is still asking for pairing.

Comment: Have you checked all of the characteristics of all of the other services that are running on your phone?

Comment: Hmm.  I just ran a peripheral app on my iPad and connected with Lightblue and it prompted me to pair.

Comment: So how it asking for pairing ?

Comment: I noticed that if you cancel the pairing, LightBlue still connects and displays services/characteristics.  My guess is that they are attempting to read one of the phone's 'in-built' characteristics that requires pairing.